Hadoop: Could not get block locations when writing file to HDFS
I'm trying to write a file to HDFS using the Hadoop Java API, but I'm encountering a java.io.ioException: Could not get block locations error. This error occurred when I tried to write data to HDFS using FSDataOutputStream. Here's a snippet of my code:
public void testCreate() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Write file:");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", "true");
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://123.456.78.99:8020");
    byte[] buff = "Hello world! My name is xxx, my student id is xxxxxx.".getBytes();
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://123.456.78.99"), conf, "root");
    Path dst = new Path(hdfsPath + "gby_xxxxxx.txt");
    FSDataOutputStream outputStream = hdfs.create(dst);
    try {
        outputStream.write(buff, 0, buff.length);
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
    FileStatus[] files = hdfs.listStatus(dst);
    for (FileStatus file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
    }
}


public void testDownload() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Download file:");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", "true");
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://123.456.78.99:8020");
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://123.456.78.99"), conf, "root");
    InputStream in = hdfs.open(new Path(hdfsPath + "gby_xxxxxx.txt"));
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("download_xxxxxx.txt");
    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, conf);
    System.out.println("Download successfully!");
}

I encountered the following error:
java.io.IOException: Could not get block locations. Source file "/gby_xxxxxx.txt" - Aborting...block==null
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DataStreamer.java:1525)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.processDatanodeOrExternalError(DataStreamer.java:1305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:668)
So far, I've tried the following steps to solve this problem:

The NameNode and DataNode logs are checked, and SIGTERM signals are frequently seen.

Restarting the Hadoop cluster was attempted.

Run hdfs fsck/to check the cluster health status without reporting any problems.


I was hoping to find help with this issue, especially understanding why I received the "Could not get block locations" error and how to successfully write files to HDFS.
